# Java Applet in WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am trying to display a Java Applet in a Java FX WebView. However, as far as I've been able to figure, it is not possible.

How can I accomplish this, without the Java FX WebView?

Comment: You are a Brave man :)

Comment: You can't. `WebView` uses webkit to render a web page; that's all. There is no support for any plugins, including Java Applets (pdf, flash, etc).

Comment: That is why I want to find another solution than WebView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gotten this working before.  I eventually gave up on JavaFX as a Java Applet for the video game i was making, due to performance issues, but it is still valid for many other purposes.  Here is the  config I used.

```
<html><head>
  <SCRIPT src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
        dtjava.launch(            {
                url : 'MyGame.jnlp'
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbed() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'MyGame.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : 1024,
                height : 768
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    <!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>MyGame</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='MyGame.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('MyGame.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a><br><hr><br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

I used JNLP to do this.  Here is my JNLP file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="MyGame.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>MyGame</title>
    <vendor>Jose</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <icon href="C:\Users\jose\Dropbox\MyGame\java7\MyGame/MyGame.ico" />
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="MyGame.jar" size="27670609" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <applet-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="MyGame" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="game.Game"  name="MyGame" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: I did a tutorial about how to embed a JavaFX application into a website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958019/embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer the question. However, I want to display an applet from a external website, *in a WebView*, in a *Java* application

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX Web View doesn't support applets so it won't work for you. You should consider another embedable browser like [JCEF](https://code.google.com/p/javachromiumembedded/) or JWebBrowser from [NativeSwing](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) or some other component

Answer (score 0):

You can use sun.applet.AppletViewer to open applet through webview. Go through the AppletViewer you can understand how you will do.

Here is the URL you found something - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/applet/AppletViewer.java.html

I hope it will help you