# JavaFX show in WEB (javascript)

Tags: web, javafx

I have an application in JavaFX but I'd also be displayed on web , Is this possible ?, how it is achieved ?. Thanks for your reply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed a JavaFX application in a HTML webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958019/embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage)