# How to deploy JavaFX as web application

Tags: browser, netbeans, web, javafx

I have create a dynamic barchart using JavaFx which displays the barchart by query data present in the mysql database. I created this project in netbeans. I am able to run this project as windows application (by converting jar file to exe).
My next challenge is to embed this project to web browser. I have jar, jnlp and html files in the dist folder of the project. I tried to run the html file in browser but they are not running it.

Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed a JavaFX application in a HTML webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958019/embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans:

1. Get a Code Signing Certificate. (They seem to cost a couple hundred dollars a year. Self-signed and unsigned don't seem to work anymore for either webstart or applet, unless you don't mind telling all your users to edit their settings https://superuser.com/questions/809027/run-unsigned-java-applets)
2. In project properties, click Request unrestricted access(Enable Signing) and then click the Edit button to set Code Signing Certificate data.
3. Right-click on the Project. Choose Set Configuration -> Run in Web Browser or  Set Configuration -> Run as Web Start
4. Build
5. Copy all the files from dist directory to your web server.