# Is it still realistic to deploy a JavaFX application using Maven in a Web Browser

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I read here that it's possible to deploy a JavaFX application into a Web Browser:
[embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958019/embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage)

Now I got stuck at the beginning when he talks about using the java packager to create an executable .jar file. I'm using Maven which uses JavaFX 18, so I followed this tutorial on how to package a java project

[java-packager-with-jdk11](https://adam-carroll.medium.com/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8)

Here I got confused with the tools he uses. I downloaded the listed tools and moved the jpackager files into the according directories. Still in cmd it gives me an "Error during initialization of boot layer": jdk.packager not found.

It's pretty worth it knowing how to create a Package from a Java Project, but is this the proper way?

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

No, not realistic.

You have a choice of alternatives.

## Legacy technologies

[That page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27958019/642706) uses legacy technologies, [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) and [Java applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet).

Java applets have been phased out by all web browser makers, so Oracle consequently decided to phase out the technology.  Java applets were first [deprecated in Java 9](https://openjdk.org/jeps/289), and later [deprecated for removal](https://openjdk.org/jeps/398) in Java 17.

Oracle no longer expects end-users to have a standalone JRE or JDK installed on their computer. So *Java Web Start* is no longer available by default for the consumer market. *Java Web Start* is no longer included in Java 11+.

However, an open-source implementation continues in the [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/) project. For some environments, such as corporations or schools where the installed base of computers is centrally managed, *OpenWebStart* may be a useful way to distribute apps.

## Ship your app with JVM bundled

Oracle now expects desktop apps and mobile apps to bundle a JVM within their product. This does mean the app must be built in editions, one edition for each supported [chip architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), but also allows the app to be tested with the same JVM that will eventually run the app.

For more info, see the Oracle white paper (PDF format), [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) of 2020-05.

New tooling is available to support this JVM-within-app packaging:

- [*Java Platform Module System (JPMS)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) in Java 9+.
- [*jlink*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) in Java 9+.
- [*jpackage*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) in Java 16+.

**Search Stack Overflow** to learn more about packaging JavaFX/OpenJFX apps for distribution. Many Questions and Answers have already been posted on the topic. The topic is rapidly evolving, including cutting-edge approaches such as using [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) for [ahead-of-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) to run [native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code).

## *Vaadin Flow*

If you want to build a [single-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) [web app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) written in pure Java without you needing to learn HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, WebSockets, Push, etc., consider using [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow). This open-source framework is based on venerable [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) technology.

You write Java code similar to that in JavaFX, defining forms by specifying widgets arranged with layout managers. Vaadin Flow then auto-generates the needed HTML+CSS+JavaScript to render the user interface remotely in the web browser while maintaining the state of your app on the server. Pure Java on server, no Java on client.

---

Comment: Also see [JPro](https://www.jpro.one/).

Comment: Thanks for the ellaborative answer, I will take a look at a packaging system.